# Socket is Showing All Ports closed

Tags: python, sockets, port

I was trying to scan ports through socket but it's show all ports closed. Here is my code:

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = input(" Please Input Ip address To Scan ")
#port = input(" ENter The Port ")
def portscanner(host):
    for port in range(1,150):
        if sock.connect_ex((host,int(port))):
            print(f"{port} Is Closed")
        else:
            print("port is open")
    
portscanner(host)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try creating a connection inside the forloop. And make sure that the input is in valid form.
You can do that using
try and catch near the sock.connect_ex to check whether you are actually sending valid host or not.

To make things faster you can use settimeout(0.25) inside the for loop too.

I meant to do this -

```
for port in range(start, end):
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.settimeout(.25)
        result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))
        if result == 0:
            print(port,'port is open')
 
        sock.close()
```